# Can we display .pdf file in between two html pages in php?

Tags: php

I have two html pages which are converted to pdf.
Now I have a pdf file and I want to add it between the two converted html pages .

I have tried converting the pdf to html but the tcpdf doesn't support this conversion of css and js.

Please help me.

Comment: How do you mean with between ?

Comment: There are a few ways to embed pdf in html.  You can google it. But if you mena something else please explain more.

Comment: The title of the question and body don't even relate

Comment: i want to embed pdf in html

Comment: do you want to display a pdf file or convert a pdf file into html ?

Comment: my task is to convert html template to pdf.
but i have .pdf file that should be kept in between that template.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert HTML + CSS to PDF with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391005/convert-html-css-to-pdf-with-php)

Comment: have you tried [PDF.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/)

Comment: I know once upon a time it was possible to `<iframe>` a PDF, not sure if browser security still allows this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use setasign\Fpdi;
require_once('tcpdf_include.php');
require_once('../FPDI/src/autoload.php');
// Original file with multiple pages 
$fullPathToFile = '../sample.pdf';
class Pdf extends Fpdi\TcpdfFpdi{
    var $_tplIdx;
}
$pdf = new pdf('P', 'px', 'A4', true, 'UTF-8', false);
$page1='<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="2" style="font-size:11px;font-family:Arial;">
</table>';
$pdf->writeHTMLCell($colWidth,300,$margin,$pagetopmargin,$page1);
$page2='';
$pdf->AddPage();
//$pdf->writeHTMLCell(235,232,495,10,$manageLogo);
$pdf->writeHTMLCell($colWidth,300,$margin,$pagetopmargin,$page2);
// THIS IS WHERE YOU GET THE NUMBER OF PAGES
$pdf -> setSourceFile('../sample.pdf');
$temp =$pdf->importPage(1);
$pdf->AddPage();   
$pdf->useTemplate($temp);
$pdf->SetMargins(30, 60, 50, true);
$pdf -> setSourceFile('../sample.pdf');
$temp =$pdf->importPage(2);
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->useTemplate($temp ,-4, 30);
$page3=' <h4>Ongoing Rent Payments</h4>
<p>Our preferred payment method for rent is Rental Rewards. (Please note that there is a small convenience fee charged for the use of the system. These fees are charged by a third-party payment processor – Rental Rewards</p> <p>The fees for the convenience of the use of the services are: (must be able to set-up fee at agent level, as there is variation)</p> <ol type="a"  style="margin-left: 20px;">';
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->writeHTMLCell($colWidth,300,$margin,$pagetopmargin-20,$page3);
ob_end_clean();
$pdf->Output('tenancy_application.pdf');
```

Answer (score 0):

PDF needs a pdf reader program installed, so embedding in html is limited by browser/OS support. Normally you can open a pdf file in a browser tab, so opening in an iframe might also work (not tested).

```
<iframe src="link to pdf"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

To embed the PDF within the page you could use [pdf.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js) from Mozilla. This would allow you to use a JavaScript snippet to pull in and render your PDF like so:

```
// If absolute URL from remote server is provided, configure CORS header on that server.
var url = '//cdn.mozilla.net/pdfjs/helloworld.pdf';

PDFJS.workerSrc = '//mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js';

// Asynchronous download of PDF
var loadingTask = PDFJS.getDocument(url);
loadingTask.promise.then(function(pdf) {

  // Fetch the first page
  var pageNumber = 1;
  pdf.getPage(pageNumber).then(function(page) {
    // Set scale
    var scale = 1.5;
    var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);

    // Prepare canvas using PDF page dimensions
    var canvas = document.getElementById('the-canvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.height = viewport.height;
    canvas.width = viewport.width;

    // Render PDF page into canvas context
    var renderContext = {
      canvasContext: context,
      viewport: viewport
    };
    var renderTask = page.render(renderContext);
  });
}, function (reason) {
  console.error(reason);
});
```

If you wanted to process your PDF upfront, rather than waiting until runtime you could convert it into HTML first by using a **file conversion API** such as [Zamzar](https://developers.zamzar.com/). You could use the API to programatically convert from PDF to HMTL (from PHP) and then use that inline.